# How to draw rectangles/circles on opencv without loading an image

Tags: c, opencv, draw

I've been messing around in opencv lately, and I've been exploring the drawing functions (cvCircle(...), cvRectangle(...), etc...). They work normally, however I can only draw them over a previously loaded image.

Is there a way to create an empty image with a custom size set by me, and draw on it?

Kind regards, 
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Check this code,

```
Mat draw(480,640,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));//create 3 channel image of size 640X480 and filled with black color
circle(draw, Point(320,240), 100, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,0);// draw a circle
rectangle(draw, Point(100,100), Point(300,300), Scalar(0,0,255),2,8,0); //draw rectangle
imshow("draw",draw);//display image
waitKey();
```

You can see more information about Mat on [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html).